# I am confused to what this list variable is doing

Tags: python

simple question. can someone please explain what cVal is doing?

```
cur = [[1,2,3],[4,8,0],[7,6,5]]

ci = 0
cj = 0

cVal = cur[ci][cj]

print(cVal)
```

Comment: Would you understand it if `cur` was `[1, 2, 3]` and `cVal` was `cur[ci]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your `cur` variable as such to better understand what happens:

```
cur = [[1,2,3],
       [4,8,0],
       [7,6,5]]
```

Then, accessing a value in a list consists in putting brackets after it. The first is about the row (first dimension) and the second about the column (second dimension).

So, `cVal = cur[ci][cj]` will return the value in the row ci-1 and column cj-1 (because python starts indexing at 0).

Comment: thats great - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`cVal` is a variable equal to `cur[0][0]` which equals `1` defined in your [2D array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_2darray.htm) `cur`.

`cur[0][0]` means "get me the value in the row `0` and column `0` of the 2D array".

Answer (score 0):

`cVal` I think it is an abbreviated form of `currentValue` just as the name mentions, it is storing the value at `ci` row and `cj` column and in the example it is `cur[0][0]` which is **0**.